# Change exchange server reply name

Tags: exchange-2003

I would like to change the reply name of my server.  For examply, when I go to http://www.mxtoolbox.com/, it displays the internal domain name of my company (which I do not want to be externally visible).

How can I change the HELO reply of my exchange server?  And does it need to be a FQDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending mail, and your MX is pointed to that server, it should be the FQDN. You want your reverse DNS to match your SMTP banner for a couple reasons. One, to not expose internal server names, and Two, to not look like a spammer.

```
Start ESM
Go to Servers -> Protocols
Select Default SMTP Virtual Server Properties
Go to Delivery tab
Click Advanced Button
Fully Qualified Domain Name - put what the outside DNS hostname is here
Restart SMTP Service.
```